# InvalidArgumentError: Index out of range using input dim 2; input has only 2 dims [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

> So a bit of context before I dive into the specifics.

I am working on building a machine learning model(encoder-decoder like) which accepts sentences in the encoder side using a gru, and in the decoder accepts an image passed through some Deep CNN stack like Inception etc and I am training this model using the COCO dataset by giving the target as a vector of 0's of shape (Batch_size,2048) for learning the similarity between the two modes of captions/images.

> ## Model Definition
>
> The model in the caption-side(encoder)

```
print("loading the caption side")

cap_input = Input(shape=(model_config['max_cap_length'],), dtype='float32', name='cap_input')
X = Masking(mask_value=0,input_shape=(model_config['max_cap_length'], model_config['output_dim']))(X)

X = Embedding(output_dim=model_config['dim_word'], input_dim=len(tokenizer.word_index), input_length=model_config['max_cap_length'])(cap_input)
X = gru(model_config['output_dim'])(X)

emb_cap = Lambda(lambda x: l2norm(x))(X)
```

> The model in the image side(decoder)

```
print("loading the image side")
image_input = Input(shape=(64, 2048), name='image_input')
X = Flatten()(image_input)
X = Dense(model_config['output_dim'])(X)
emb_image = Lambda(lambda x: l2norm(x))(X)
```

> The merge/concatenate layer

```
print ("loading the joined model")
merged = concatenate([emb_cap, emb_image])
```

> Model compilation and definition

```
model = Model(inputs=[cap_input, image_input], outputs=[merged])
model.compile(optimizer=model_config['optimizer'], loss=contrastive_loss)
```

> ## the model summary is as follows:

[a pic of the model summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMFVd.png)

Now when I try to fit the model with one batch of data I run into this error.

> ## model fitting code

```
model.fit(a,b,epochs = 1)
```

> where:

```
a = [(batchsize,49),(batchsize,64,2048)] 
b = (batchsize,2048)

a[0] => The caption-side where 49 is the max length to which all other captions in the dataset are padded.

a[1] => The image side where each image is preprocessed to be of shape (64,2048)

b    => The output where 2048 corresponds to the "merged" layer where I am concatenating two tensors of dim (batchsize,1024)
```

> This is the complete stack trace of the error

---

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-147-e50fb5e10e5c> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(a,b,epochs = 1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    878           initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
    879           steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
--> 880           validation_steps=validation_steps)
    881 
    882   def evaluate(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, mode, validation_in_fit, **kwargs)
    308           if ins and isinstance(ins[-1], int):
    309             # Do not slice the training phase flag.
--> 310             ins_batch = slice_arrays(ins[:-1], batch_ids) + [ins[-1]]
    311           else:
    312             ins_batch = slice_arrays(ins, batch_ids)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in slice_arrays(arrays, start, stop)
    524       if hasattr(start, 'shape'):
    525         start = start.tolist()
--> 526       return [None if x is None else x[start] for x in arrays]
    527     else:
    528       return [None if x is None else x[start:stop] for x in arrays]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    524       if hasattr(start, 'shape'):
    525         start = start.tolist()
--> 526       return [None if x is None else x[start] for x in arrays]
    527     else:
    528       return [None if x is None else x[start:stop] for x in arrays]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in _slice_helper(tensor, slice_spec, var)
    652         ellipsis_mask=ellipsis_mask,
    653         var=var,
--> 654         name=name)
    655 
    656 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in strided_slice(input_, begin, end, strides, begin_mask, end_mask, ellipsis_mask, new_axis_mask, shrink_axis_mask, var, name)
    818       ellipsis_mask=ellipsis_mask,
    819       new_axis_mask=new_axis_mask,
--> 820       shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask)
    821 
    822   parent_name = name

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py in strided_slice(input, begin, end, strides, begin_mask, end_mask, ellipsis_mask, new_axis_mask, shrink_axis_mask, name)
   9332       else:
   9333         message = e.message
-> 9334       _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   9335   # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
   9336   if begin_mask is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: Index out of range using input dim 2; input has only 2 dims [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/
```

So any ideas on why this is happening? and also could someone explain what the error means??

Comment: Could you try expanding the shape of `b`. By first doing `b = np.array(b)` and then `b = b.reshape((b.shape[0], b.shape[1], 1))`. This is because some layers require the shape of the label to be `(No_of_samples, length, 1)` format.